# libcurl easy vs multi interface

Tags: c, http, curl, libcurl

I want to use the libcurl library to post data to 4 urls simultaneously, every 30-120 seconds or so.

What is faster is this case, using libcurl_easy manually or using libcurl_multi ? The doc is very sparse and I haven't found a real answer anywhere. I just want to know which would be faster, doesn't matter if its by a very small margin.

Also, I know libcurl handles have keepalive as long as I don't reset them, so in my case they will no time out inbetween requests ?

edit : I realise this seems illogical to optimise if I run every few seconds, but when I post it has to be as fast as possible.

Comment: _Profile first_. Also, does it really matter if you're doing this at most once every 30 seconds?

Comment: Use multi when you want more than one request to be carried out at the same time

Answer (score 3):

There's really no speed difference between the easy and the multi interface. The easy interface is actually internally implemented as a wrapper around the multi interface so eventually they're running the same code anyway.

The multi interface offers a non-blocking API for doing many transfers in parallel. If you just want to do a single request in a synchronous fashion, there's really no reason not to just go with the easiest: the easy interface.